# JQuery - add more than 1 comment doesnt work

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

By this code I add comments to a posts. But there is a problem - the first comment work, but i am not able to add next. I use livequery, so it shold work. Can you help me?

```
$('form.comment_form').livequery('submit', function a()  
  {
      var element = $(this);        
      var wall_post_id = element.attr("id");
       var wall_message = $('#comment_text'+wall_post_id).attr('value');

        $.post("home/add_comment", $(this).serialize(), function(response)
        {
            if(response.error == "0")
            {
          $("div#comments"+wall_post_id).replaceWith(response.message);
            }
            else if(response.error == "1")
            {
               alert(response.message);
               return false;
            }
      }, "json");
      return false;
   });
```

Comment: This would probably get you more productive answers if it was on StackOverflow.com

Comment: The "Belongs-on" tags are deprecated as per a few discussions on meta such as: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10216/can-we-disallow-the-use-of-belongs-on-xxxxxxx-and-not-programming-related-tag

Comment: what happens when you try and add the next? error? nothing? do you see the post going through with a dev plugin like Firebug?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is when you use the replaceWith it is completely removing that DOM element. So the second time it runs for the second comment there is no DIV that matches any more so there is nothing to replace. Try appending instead. See the following code:

```
$('form.comment_form').livequery('submit', function a()  
{
  var element = $(this);        
  var wall_post_id = element.attr("id");
  var wall_message = $('#comment_text'+wall_post_id).attr('value');

    $.post("home/add_comment", $(this).serialize(), function(response)
    {
        if(response.error == "0")
        {
         $("div#comments"+wall_post_id).append(response.message);
        }
        else if(response.error == "1")
        {
           alert(response.message);
           return false;
        }
  }, "json");
  return false;
});
```